# Django with html chartjs

Tags: html, django, web, django-templates, chart.js

"I use Django to create a web app with HTML, and I want to change the format of numbers in the graph from 123456.123456 to 123,456.12. I've tried using floatformat:'2g' or .toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","), but the values in each point are separated by commas, like [1123,2212]. The expected result should be like 1,123 and 2,212 as usual, but in the graph, I get:

Point 1: 1
Point 2: 123
Point 3: 2
Point 4: 212

Please help."
This is my first time asking on Stack Overflow. If anything's wrong, I'm sorry.

my code :

```
new Chart(chartLineCanvas, {

    type: 'line',

    data: {

        labels: labels,

        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Total Sales (Baht)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
                data: data
            },
            {
                label: 'Average Sales Present (Baht)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 165, 0, 1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)',
                data: Array(data.length).fill(data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) /data.length),
            },
            {
                label: 'Average Sales Before(Baht)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)',
                data: Array(averagedata.length).fill(averagedata.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / averagedata.length),
            },
        ],
    },
    options: {
        mode: 'index',
        bodyFontSize: 20,
        locale: 'en-US',
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                    var datasetLabel = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
                    var value = tooltipItem.yLabel;
                    return datasetLabel + ': ' + value.toLocaleString('en-US', {
                        style: 'decimal',
                        minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                        maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                    });
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: what is the value of tooltipItem.yLabel?